# Descargar PDF que se encuentra en carpeta dentro del proyecto ASP.NET MVC EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, archivo, pdf, entity-framework

Buen día compañeros necesito descargar un PDF que guarde en una carpeta dentro del proyecto, en la BD guarde la ruta de dicho documento
asi: `\Content\EmpresaX\No_3453452342_Factura-453-2WA.pdf`

cree un botón en mi vista Details el cual al presionar quisiera descargara el PDF o lo mostrara en otra ventana del navegador, resultados que no eh conseguido eh intentado varias maneras pero sinceramente no se que pueda estar haciendo mal

Aqui el codigo de mi controlador

```
[Route("~/Facturas/Download")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFileAsync(int? id)
        {

string FilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\EmpresaX\No_3453452342_Factura-453-2WA.pdf");
        WebClient User = new WebClient();
        Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
        }


return null;
}
```

en si este fragmento de código funciona pero no hace nada al final , si logra acceder al archivo, como es PDF tengo entendido que se debe convertir en arreglo de bytes y si lo hace mas después de todo esto no pasa nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizando  [`File(fileContents, contentType, fileContents)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_File_System_Byte___System_String_System_String_) especificando el nombre del archivo como ultimo parametro:

```
[Route("~/Facturas/Download")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(int? id)
{

        string FilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~\Content\EmpresaX\No_3453452342_Factura-453-2WA.pdf");
        WebClient User = new WebClient();
        Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
        if (FileBuffer != null)
        {
            return File(FileBuffer, "application/pdf", "nombre-archivo-pdf.pdf");
        }


       return Content("El archivo no fue  encontrado", "text/plain");
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta Fue lo que necesitaba, me tomare el atrevimiento de editarla ya que cometí un par de errores  como el método HttpPost deberia ser HttpGet asi como async

Comment: me surge una duda el archivo lo tengo en ruta dentro del proyecto recien habia encontrado esta solucion `public  FileResult Download(int? id)
        {var ruta = Server.MapPath(id+@"\Ejemplo.pdf");
            return File(ruta, "application/pdf", id.ToString()+"Exito.pdf");}` a tu punto de vista cual es mejor y por que, en la tuya (a mi parecer mas elegante) se efectua el proceso de conversion del archivo a bytes en la mostrada (mas simple) es una descarga directa asi tambien quisiera saber como afecta al momento de subir el proyecto a producion

Comment: Cual es tu duda exactamente?

Comment: edite el comentario anterior para agregar la duda ahi

Comment: En realidad no hay diferencia entre ambos. Existe una sobrecargar del metodo `File` donde puedes pasarle la ruta absoluta del archivo que al final lo convirte tambien a `bytes[]`

Comment: Exelente muchas gracias queria es bueno saberlo para saber que se esta codificando muchas gracias